# linux kernel list_head vs empty entry that contains list_head

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to understand how this list works, by looking at the macro expansion of list_for_each_entry, the condition to exit the for is

```
&pos->list_member != head
```

but I see code that written like this and works fine, I don't understand why it works

```
struct entry {
    int some_var;
    struct list_head list;
};

struct global {
    struct list_head entries_list;
};

struct global Global;
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&global.entries_list)
entry = kmalloc(new_entry..)
list_add_tail(&entry,&Global.entries_list);
list_for_each_entry(entry,&Global.entries_list,list) {

}
```

So by the end of the for, I should expect `&entry->list == &Global.entries_list`?
How is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete code? There should be some initialization for `Global`...

Comment: sorry, it is not the complete code, just example, off course there is call to INIT_HEAD_LIST of global.entries_list

Comment: It's a circular double list implementation. It has a root node that doesn't contain any payload and children which are actual nodes of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So by the end of the for, I should expect `&entry->list == &Global.entries_list`?

Yes.

> How is this possible?

Condition above means that `entry` is *fake*: it is not an element in the list, but just a raw pointer, which satisfies to given condition.